# Can`t run quasar cordova app in android-studio emulator gradle Ubuntu 18

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ubuntu, quasar-framework

I have some quasar-framework cordova project. It work normally on android devices, on xcode emulator, on ios services I want build it and run in android studio 3.5 ubuntu 18.04, but I have some troubles with it, exactly 
- I can`t add configuration Android app - no module

What I do:

1. clone my project from git
2. go to project folder
3. install packages with yarn
4. gradle init
5. build app with command  `quasar build -m cordova -T android`
6. build success!
7. open android studio file->new->import project
8. choose my project folder
9. project build success in android studio
10. But I can`t run it, add configuration Android app - no module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was solved by installing Android-Studio using snap, before that it was downloaded from the site in the archive.